# Should the [css] and [css3] tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I can't think of any good reason why the [css3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css3) tag should exist on CR at all.  There is currently a [discussion going on over on Meta SO as to when the css3 tag is appropriate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299916/when-is-the-css3-tag-appropriate).

- CSS3 is not a well defined "version" of CSS
- There's no way to specify to the user agent that we want to use CSS3 over any other "version" of CSS:  the UA either understands it or ignores it
- Questions end up getting tagged with [css3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css3) but not [css](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css)

Comment: I think they should be used separatelly. There were new selectors, new syntax on pseudo-elements, different behaviours, animations, new units and 'functions' (which didn't exist before). And plenty more. CSS2.1 is not the same as CSS3. But I'm not sure if it would go by as a meta tag or not.

Comment: By that logic, we should have version specific tags for every technology (databases, languages, etc.).  There's no version specific tag for C, PostgreSQL, or Ruby.  There *are* version specific tags for PHP, and Python.  However, these are technologies where we can actively choose the version.  You can't do that with CSS or JavaScript (and you can only kinda do it with HTML).

Comment: I think that the HTML version you pick will determine the CSS version and some Javascript aspects, like HTML5 libraries.

Comment: Nope.  The only thing the HTML doctype does is tell the UA how to validate it and whether or not the browser should render in standards or [quirks mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).  The specific version of HTML does not dictate whether or not it goes into quirks mode.

Comment: This "discussion" could go on and on. And for your information, the presence of a specific doctipe really dictates how certain aspects of a webpage behave and render.

Comment: You said "the HTML version you pick will determine the CSS version", that's not the same thing as "your document will render in quirks mode" (and really, all that means for most people is that the box-model is calculated slightly different).  The CSS properties and selectors are otherwise all the same.  Again, the version of HTML has nothing to do with any of that, only specific doctypes do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree... there's no real reason for a stand-alone css3 tag.

There are only 13 questions with [css3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css3) that are not already [css](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css).  [See this search result](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css3+-css). In those cases it is clear that each one would be satisfied with a simple [css](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css) tag.

[Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/css/synonyms) is the synonymization suggestion.

Comment: I can actually vote on that one!